# Are Cortana and Master Chief in Love?

Tags: halo-series

Are Cortana and Master Chief in love?

I've read [conflicting](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/forums/6e35355aecdf4fd0acdaee3cc4156fd4/topics/cortana-revived-in-halo-5/1f054f6f-6c5c-4781-ad1c-f94ffb840343/posts?page=5) [answers](http://halo.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Does_cortana_love_master_chief) around the web, but is there an answer with a source in Halo canon?

Comment: Hello, I think that this question is based on opinions, so I think that it must be closed.

Comment: It is not opinion based imo. Bungie has an official answer or not, regarding those two lovebirds. Not what someone thinks about the relationship.

Comment: @Mathias711 Any question that requires an answer from the developer is a question we cannot allow here.

Comment: @Frank I think it is more asking for some statement made by the developer in the past, not wanting to ask the developers directly. He literally asks "is there an official answer from Bungie?"

Comment: @Mathias711 And that's exactly what our developer intent reason is for.  If the only people that can answer the question are the developers, they don't make for good questions here.  Asking for a statement from the developers is still asking for developer intent.  Just trying to route around our close reason.

Comment: Take out the developer stuff and this is just a question of [canon & lore](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7698/28182), which is on-topic. There is even a section on the [Halo Wiki](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Cortana#Personality) addressing their 'relationship': *"She frequently joked about having a relationship with John-117 and it is often implied that the two characters **have developed some form of attachment**. In Halo: The Fall of Reach, she says to Dr. Halsey that John-117 is "attractive in a primitive animal sort of way" while examining a photo of him."* (cont.)

Comment: *"In Halo 3, his mere presence and reminder of his promise to her are enough for her to pull herself together to help him. In Halo 4, she sacrifices herself to save John and one of the last things she does is touch him with a life-sized hologram, something she had always wanted to do. When John is devastated by her upcoming death, saying it's his job to look out for her, she tells him they are supposed to look out for each other and they did. John-117 is clearly torn up by her death afterwards. "*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no. They are not in love in a romantic sense, but they do love each other.

Halo 4 serves as the best exploration of the relationship between the two of them and really shows how they see one another. They rely on each other constantly and for everything and as they face all of their struggles, they do it together. Cortana has to face her own madness and Chief has to not only face the biggest and most unknown threat he ever has, but he has to do so while his best friend struggles for her life.

Josh Holmes, the creative director for Halo 4 and the Halo franchise, has classified their relationship as best friends on several occasions [[1]](https://vimeo.com/51427852) [[2]](http://www.engadget.com/2013/04/02/halo-4-as-a-love-story-the-personal-origins-of-cortanas-breakd/). And while they don't shy away from calling it love, and a love story, they also don't refer to it as anything more than platonic love.

That said, Microsoft as a whole doesn't seem to be as willing to commit to what to call it. They even [poke fun at it themselves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96qiO7DHI1A) with their new Cortana voice command system.

So yes, the Chief and Cortana are in love with each other. But indications from 343 at the moment are that it is platonic, not romantic love.

Comment: Considering what ive seen from the trailers of 5, pushes that platonic love.

Comment: My impression from playing the games was definitely romantic love, but developer's word beats gamer's impression.

Comment: Soooo can we say that Master Chief is friendzoned by Cortana?

Answer (score 0):

Cortana's brain was modeled after Dr. Halsey's, and Dr. Halsey loves Master Chief, but not romantically. Dr. Halsey loves him like a child, so so does Cortana. So Cortana tried to protect him from whatever she's planning to do in Halo 5.

Answer (score -2):

You could say "maybe" there is no "official" answer - I don't think one will come anytime soon BUT in the sequence of Halo 4

> Cortana leaves chief by saving him in the end game. [CUTSCENE](https://youtu.be/hnkOLCwu-HM?t=28s)